# Запись в куки, php

Tags: php, cookie, сессия

есть файл "login.php", в нём я создаю куку. Потом я беру значение полей. Вопрос... Как мне записать значение какого-либо поля в эту же самую куку?

Comment: а как вы создаёте куки? Точно так же и перезаписывайте.

Comment: но я беру значение с полей же и выходит я не могу после "вывода" записовать в куку новые значения

Comment: "вывод" делайте после записи в куки, т.е., вместо вывода сохраняйте значение в переменную, делайте запись в куки, и потом делайте вывод в браузер.

Comment: Поля вы получите при обновлении страницы после отправки формы. Вот в этот момент и обновляйте куки.